# Replace double loops python with apply

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, duplicates, apply

Does anyone know if it is possible to replace a double loop in python with something faster like the apply function ?
For instance, I have this dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["col_1"] = ["hello", "salut","hello", "bye", "bye","hi","hello", "hello"]
df["col_2"] = ["dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "mouse","dog","cat"]
df["col_3"] = [100,45,100,51,51,32,100,85]
```

and this function :

`def f (l1, l2):
    if list(l1) == list(l2) :
        return 1
    else:
        return 0`

Which returns 1 if 2 lists are identical and 0 otherwise. I would like to apply this function to create a column "similar" like this :[image]

Which I can easily do with a double loop but I would like to do this faster with less complexity.

Thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to find col combinations that have duplicates, and mark them as `1` in column "similar". `pandas.DataFrame.duplicated` does exactly that, you just have to do:

```
df.duplicated(keep=False)
```

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html#pandas.DataFrame.duplicated , `keep=False` will mark all duplicates as `True`.

Then you just need to convert boolean to int:

```
df['similar'] = list(map(int, df.duplicated(keep=False)))
```

Comment: Thanks  that is 10 times faster !